# How to show Activity indicator 5 seconds before hello world

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to show Activity indicator 5 seconds before "Hello world". can you help me please.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello world!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showContent: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ showContent: true });
    }, 5000);
  }

  render() {
    const { showContent } = this.state;

    return showContent ? (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello world!</Text>
      </View>
    ) : (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Good answer...!! Set flex and styles for view.

Comment: Error "Invariant Violation: App(...):Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."